# Apex governor limit warning emails

Tags: apex, governorlimits

I have VF pages linked to custom controllers which query thousands of organization records and display them. I get the following email

> Operation: /apex/SingleTicketAudit By user/organization: ###### Caused
>   the following Apex resource warnings: Number of query rows: 50001 out
>   of 50000

I checked my logs and it looks like SQL query limit is 50,000. This is a custom controller to generate a special report and I need to be querying thousands of records of data. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use readonly for vf page in order to increase this limit to 1 million rows.

However you won't be able to make any dmls in read only mode.

**This document would help you:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_readonly_context_pagelevel.htm